# How to retrieve header values from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How can I retrieve the header values from a JTable?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by header values? do you mean cell values?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the `getColumnName(int)` method

```
jTable.getColumnName(columnIndex)
```

Comment: sure. that is simple!

Answer (score 3):

It is not obvious that the Column name and the header name are the same. To get the header name:
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).getHeaderValue()